# Is there any way to destroy MDW reference

Tags: ms-access

I have an access 2003 file that someone secured with a mdw. However, that person isn't there anymore and the mdw file was lost. Can we do something, anything, to open and read that file ?

Thank you

Comment: How would a password recovery tool help me open an access database when I don't have the mdw to open it ?

Comment: There are two types of password recovery, database password and Jet ULS passwords. Without the system database, I'm not sure there's any need for password recovery, since you don't know the usernames, either (well, you know one user name, ADMIN, but you don't know the SID that's associated with it, and that won't give you access to a properly-secured MDB, anyway). I think you might want to Google "jet user-level security recovery" instead. The first link that comes up there claims the capability of recovering what you need even without the workgroup file (though it's only in the pay version).