# Is it possible to bypass DAO group/user security of old access database?

Tags: security, ms-access, dao

I'm trying to build new DB manager compatible with Windows 7 for old software which i don't have the code to. I am using 64bit Windows 7, and therefore cannot install the necessary DAO driver that was used to connect to the database.

Unfortunately, the database is protected using the DAO user/workgroup privileges. is there any way to extract the information from the database or bypass the security measures on that file?

Comment: You will need the *.mdw and log in, then http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/0bbf4c91-f43e-4f66-bb8c-994d1a8b5f19

Comment: if i had the MDW file i wouldn't have any problems. right now I'm trying to reverse engineer the original program to get the connection string for the DAO. but surely there must be a quicker way...

Comment: I think quicker ways may involve money: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751575/is-there-any-way-to-destroy-mdw-reference

Answer (score 0):

You don’t mention what version of Access you have to work with.

If you have access 2010, or 2013, you can open the database using the workgroup security file with a shortcut.

2010

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"
"c:\RidesDev\SkiRides\RidesXP\RidesXP.mdb"
/wrkgrp "c:\RidesDev\SkiRides\RidesXP\Rides.mdw"
```

2013

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE"
"c:\RidesDev\SkiRides\RidesXP\RidesXP.mdb"
 /wrkgrp "c:\RidesDev\SkiRides\RidesXP\Rides.mdw"
```

The above shortcuts are of course one line and each part being separated by a space.

Once you opened the database with the above shortcut then this specifies the workgroup security file. You will be prompted for user and password. Once you done this, then can from the Access file menu close the database. (Do NOT exit Access). At this point you can create a blank new 2010 accDB database. And then import all objects from the old mdb database.

Note the above works by you NOT exiting Access – this means you will remain attached to the security group. Since you remain attached to the security workgroup you are able to import all objects from the older mdb to the new accDB you just created. At this point I would then exit Access and then launch the newly created database.

The new database will thus be free of all security, and your exit + re-enter of Access and launching Access without the security group shortcut means you are opening the new database without workgroup security.

Above assumes you have the correct user + password logon with full rights to the database. If the database has startup code and forms that you can't by-pass, then you can create a blank database and again specify the above workgroup security file for the new database and that also would allow you to import the objects into your new blank database. The result should be an accDB file without any security.